# Запутался в решении

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая считывает три строки по очереди, а затем выводит их в той же последовательности, каждую на отдельной строчке.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаются три строки, каждая на отдельной строке.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести введенные строки в той же последовательности, каждую на отдельной строке.

Примечание. Для считывания текста используйте команду input(), для печати текста на экране используйте команду print().

Моё решение:

```
a = input()
print("I was")
print("born")
print("this way")
b = input()
print("I love")
print("Python")
print("so much")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого результата можно добиться несколькими способами. Более простой, но более длинный способ:

```
a = input("Введите первую строку: ")
b = input("Введите вторую строку: ")
c = input("Введите третью строку: ")
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Или можно сделать короче:

```
a = input("Введите первую строку: ")
b = input("Введите вторую строку: ")
c = input("Введите третью строку: ")
print(f"{a}\n{b}\n{c}")
```

Надеюсь, что смог Вам помочь!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Главное в самом начале я делал верно, но что-то мне не понравилось и я код не завершил и начал переделывать в итоге сам запутался!;))

Comment: Бывает :) Рад, что помог!

Answer (score 2):

1. где у вас в приведённом коде 3 считанных строчки (по сути 3 `input`)?
2. где у вас в коде вывод считанных строк (которые вы записали в переменные)?
3. почему вы выводите какие-то левые тексты, а не то, что получено с помощью команд `input`?

пример:

```
text1 = input('введите первую строку: ')
#какой-то код
print(text1) # вывод первой строки
```

Comment: Несовсем понял...! text1 = input('I was')
text2 = input('born')
text3 = input('this way')
print(text1)

Comment: зачем вы вводите `I was born this way`? Это пользователь будет вводить с клавиатуры, а ваша программа должны 3 раза принять ввод, 3 раза записать в переменные и 3 раза потом вывести значение этих переменных

Comment: Кажись понял..так? text1 = input()
text2 = input()
text3 = input()
print(text1)
print(text2)
print(text3)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input() # вводим первую строку, жмем enter
b = input() # вводим вторую строку, жмем enter
c = input() # вводим третью строку, жмем enter

print(a) # выводим первую строку
print(b) # выводим вторую строку
print(c) # выводим третью строку
```

Answer (score 0):

Ловите решение в 2 строки

```
a, b, c = input(), input(), input()
print(a+'\n'+b+'\n'+c)
```

Comment: Питонист, здравствуйте! Я Grand IT (просто обновил аккаунт). Вам понравилась VisualStudio Code? Я тут недавно узнал про CLion. Лично ей не пользовался, но IDE от JetBrains мне нравятся.

Comment: А, я-то думал, куда девался Grand IT? И что за Anaconda такая? На **VisualStudio Code** работаю вовсю, курсы прохожу, всё нормально вроде)

Comment: Наверно жалко было потерять репутацию(((

Comment: А у меня закончилась возможность задавать вопросы, поэтому я и обновил аккаунт. Но теперь Вы знаете, что Anaconda - это я :)

Comment: Ааа, ну да, понятно